# How to get formula field compile size from api

Tags: metadata-api, formula-field, tooling-api

Is there a way to get the compile size of a formula field through the metadata api or the tooling api?  I have found "calculatedFormula" on the metadata api and "formula" on the tooling api but neither seem to provide the compile size.

Comment: I'm going to guess "no," since I've never seen such a way to find this, but here's hoping I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally I found the idea - [Calculate Current Compile Size for formula fields](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000h25DAAQ), which has been merged with [Formula Debug Tool](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000jYV3AAM).

Based on those ideas, I'd also say that the current answer is "no" with respect to the APIs.

I'd suggest commenting on the [Formula Debug Tool](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000jYV3AAM) idea to see if they can expand it out to the APIs when implemented.